# Is there a word for re-engaging in a habit one used to have?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm not sure there is such a word, but I'm looking for a word, which expresses the intention or execution of re-engaging an old habit, which one used to have.

For example, if Joe used to play piano daily in his twenties but lost interest due to lack of time after starting a family, is there such an expression, that Joe can say "I used to play piano daily a long time ago and plan to * this habit soon again" (where * is the expression I'm looking for)?

Comment: It's not a single word but _get back into smth_ is commonly used. "I used to play piano daily a long time ago and plan to *get back into it*."

Comment: Also, habit is probably not the right word here. A habit is a personal behavior, good (like getting up early) or bad (like smoking). An activity like playing the piano is a hobby or pastime.

Comment: If it's a habit of substance abuse, you say *fall off the wagon* or more generally for bad behavior, *He's back to his old tricks again*.

Comment: "relapse" can be either tongue-in-cheek or sadly accurate

Comment: I really do not get why people post the negative ones, when only the positive ones are being requested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**"resume a habit, a hobby, etc"**

- [**resume**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/resume) - (verb) -  take up again after interruption.

> - [**"Soon after the holidays, the children were back in school, and I resumed my hobby of sewing."**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=TORZXr0xUMYC&pg=PA139&dq=I+resumed+my+hobby&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi389XIqeDOAhVLGZAKHWrHC0YQ6AEIJDAB)
> - [**"In England, about one-third of primiparous women resumed intercourse by 6 weeks."**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=KZLubBxJEwEC&pg=PA1007&dq=In+England,+about+one-third+of+primiparous+women+resumed+intercourse+by+6+weeks&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbvO7lqODOAhXHi5AKHS1mBmMQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=In%20England%2C%20about%20one-third%20of%20primiparous%20women%20resumed%20intercourse%20by%206%20weeks&f=false)
> - [**"The Christian" was first published in November 19025 and discontinued in 1928.  The magazine resumed publication in July 1934."**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=8e1_AQAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&dq=resumed&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-gd3Sp-DOAhVElpAKHS9rD9s4KBDoAQhZMAg#v=onepage&q=resumed&f=false)
> - [**"About noon we resumed our journey, and soon after five P. M. we reached Kaau."**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=ubOGAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA224&dq=%22we+resumed%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSnY-FqeDOAhXHvJAKHdfOC6IQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22we%20resumed%22&f=false)

Answer (score 4):

If it is an undesirable hobby, such as excess consumption of alcoholic beverages,  "backsliding" is sometimes used. Somewhat more common is the phrase "fell off the wagon".

Answer (score 3):

*"I used to play piano daily a long time ago and plan to **[take it up](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-sth-up)** again soon.*"

Answer (score 3):

One takes up a hobby. "I took up snorkeling when visiting the reef."

[Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/take-up_1):

> to start doing something regularly as a habit, job, or interest

Comment: So, here, it would be: to take up x again.

Answer (score 2):

Revert to type

> revert to type
>   Popularity: Bottom 10% of words
>   Definition of revert to type
>   chiefly British
>   :  to go back to doing what one usually does

Also if the old habit was considered a bad one the term relapse is appropriate.

In the case of renewing interest in something that used to be a passion,like playing piano, one might say: 
"He plans to rekindle his passion of piano playing."

Or as often is expressed by musicians who have taken a hiatus from their instrument: "I plan to pick up ( instrument name) again."

Answer (score -1):

**Retrogress**
/ˌrɛtrə(ʊ)ˈɡrɛs/
verb

1. go back to an earlier state, typically a worse one.
   "she retrogressed to the starting point of her rehabilitation"

**Relapse**
/ˈriːlaps/

1. a deterioration in someone's state of health after a temporary improvement.

Comment: You need to add the sources for these definitions to your answer.